# Handling EOF, white spaces, and new lines in ANTLR

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to write a grammar to handle binary numbers and compute their values:

```
grammar T;

options
{
backtrack=true;
}

prog : 

    (b2 = binarynum NEWLINE)+ EOF {System.out.println($binarynum.value);}
    |
    b1 = binarynum  EOF {System.out.println($binarynum.value);}
    ;

binarynum returns [double value] :

    s1=string '.' s2=string
    {$value = $s1.value + $s2.value/Math.pow(2.0,$s2.length);}
    |
    string
    {$value = $string.value;}
    ;

string returns [double value, int length] : 

    bit s2=string
    {$value = $bit.value*Math.pow(2.0,$s2.length)+$s2.value; $length = $s2.length+1; }
    | 
    bit
    {$value = $bit.value; $length = 1; }
    ;

bit returns [double value] :   

    '0' 
    { $value = 0;}
    | 
    '1'
    { $value = 1;}
    ;

NEWLINE: ('\r')? '\n' {skip();} ;
```

Java code:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class TestT {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Create an TLexer that feeds from that stream
        //TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(System.in));
        TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRFileStream("input.txt"));

        // Create a stream of tokens fed by the lexer
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

        // Create a parser that feeds off the token stream
        TParser parser = new TParser(tokens);

        // Begin parsing at rule prog
        parser.prog();
    }
}
```

Input File ("input.txt") contains:

```
11111.111
1000
1000.1
```

`Error: line 3:4 missing EOF at '.'`

I first tested the code with having just one input with the prog statement as the following:

```
    prog : 
        binarynum EOF {System.out.println($binarynum.value);}
         ;
```

Everything works out just fine when I do the above modification with one input, however I can't seem to get the hang of it when using multiple inputs separated by new lines.

Can someone please help me out and tell me where I went wrong.

I also have another question, when should the EOF not be included in the grammar? When I tested the grammar for one input after removing the EOF from the grammar I received no errors and a correct output.

Comment: Switching to ANTLR 4 could fix the problem immediately. If not, I'd be happy to answer any questions you have when targeting that version.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use version 3 ( I have a programming based exam   later on which his related to parsing,antlr etc.. where only version 3 is allowed )

Comment: @280Z28 can I get some help, pretty please :/

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please help me out and tell me where I went wrong.

Your lexer is skipping line breaks while your parser uses them. Remove `{skip();}` from the lexer rule.

> I also have another question, when should the EOF not be included in the grammar?

You'll usually have it at the end of your top level parser rule, which will force the parser to consume the entire input.